# How to handle "sporadic" multiple measures?

Tags: r, data-structures, statistics

I find myself analyzing data that I don't really know how to handle. I accept any suggestion, even a keyword would help. Ideally, I am looking for hints to run a Bayesian hierarchical model on Jags (I am working on R and RJags).

So imagine having e.g. 10 individuals that report their perceptions on 5 items.
The difficulty is due to the fact that for some individuals, I have two or three perceptions for one (or more) item, in other cases I may have `NA`s. So the structure of the data is inherently unbalanced. Here is an example of the data structure (id is the identifier and Kn the item being measured):

```
    [id] [K1] [K2] [K3] [K4] [K5] [K6]
[1]    1   ??  -1    2    3    -3    4
[2]    2   NA  -2    1    2    -4    5
[3]    3   0   NA    NA   3    -2    3
[4]    4   NA  -2    2    NA   NA    5
[5]    5   2   -1    3    4    -5    4
[6]    6   1   NA    1    1    -1    3
```

The solution I came out with is to duplicate the rows for those individuals with multiple measurements, and to "fill in" the row for the items other than the one measured multiple times with the only available measure for those. For a simple example, let individual 1 to have two available measures on item K1 (e.g. 1 and 2):

```
    [id] [K1] [K2] [K3] [K4] [K5] [K6]
[1]    1   1   -1    2    3    -3    4
[2]    1   2   -1    2    3    -3    4
[3]    2  NA   -2    1    2    -4    5
[4]    3   0   NA    NA   3    -2    3
[5]    4  NA  -2    2    NA    NA    5
[6]    5   2   -1    3    4    -5    4
[7]    6   1   NA    1    1    -1    3
```

`id` is the individual identifier, and now id==1 has two different measures for K1. I cannot take an average, I really need a way to systematically include this additional information. Then, I run a hierarchical model in JAGS using a nested indexing to come up with one coefficient for each individual, instead of one coefficient for each row. I wonder that an alternative might be to use a "selector", a matrix of `0`s and value `1` indicating the item being measured. Is it possible to implement this in Jags? I don't find examples of similar data structures anywhere. This could resemble a kind of very unbalanced repeated-measure data structure, but actually the measure is contemporaneous.

Comment: What's the difference between ?? and NA? You say 5 items, but have 6 variables. Do you mean you have 6 items?

Comment: How married are you to using JAGS?  Tweaking this data to work within a repeated measures ANOVA (depending on missingness) might be trivial.  Alternatively, although assumptions are likely to be violated (when are they not), you might very well be able to get an lme4 mixed effects model to give you some sort of analysis.  Regardless, it is almost certainly best not to make up observations to make your data happier.

Comment: @pavel : the "??" stands for "should I use value 1 or 2", I can change that it was just to point to the problem

Comment: @rpierce: JAGS allows me to incorporate prior information. I share your point of view about duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a long table with id, measure_id and value instead of a wide table with NA's:

```
n.subjects <- 10
new.df <- data.frame(        id = rep(old.df$id, 6),
                     measure_id = rep(1:6, each=n.subjects)
                         values = c(old.df$K1, 
                                    old.df$K2, 
                                    old.df$K3, 
                                    old.df$K4, 
                                    old.df$K5,
                                    old.df$K6))

df <- df[!is.na(df$value)]  # remove measurements with NA's
```

Then you can easily modify your JAGS code to fit the new format.

Comment: I'd add that parvel's earlier comment may have a role to play, i.e. if you've accidentally stored ?? rather than NA. you may have problems still.

Comment: No, the `??` has only illustrative character, is not on the code.